# flyspell overrides company key bindings

Tags: latex, auctex, company-mode, flyspell

I have the following in my `init` file.

```
;; ======= Company mode set up ============
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
  :config
  (use-package company-irony :ensure t :defer t)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "TAB") 'company-complete-common-or-cycle)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "<tab>") 'company-complete-common-or-cycle)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "S-TAB") 'company-select-previous)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'company-select-previous)
  (setq company-require-match 'never)
  (setq company-idle-delay              nil
        company-minimum-prefix-length   2
        company-show-numbers            t
        company-tooltip-limit           20
        company-dabbrev-downcase        nil
        company-backends                '((company-irony company-gtags)))
  :bind ("C-;" . company-complete-common))
```

I also use `helm-flyspell` like so:

```
(require 'helm-flyspell)
(define-key flyspell-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'helm-flyspell-correct)
```

Now when I do `C-.` it gives me a helm buffer with the usual ability to select the correct spelling. The problem is when I want to do `company-complete-common` I do `C-;`. However, I have found that 
`C-;` is bound to the variable `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word` whenever I am in `latex` mode.

What I want is for `C-;` to be bound to `company-complete-common` at all times and `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word` bound to some other key combination. Perhaps map it to **f12**. How can I do this without messing up what I already have? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just customize `flyspell-auto-correct-binding` to `<f12>`.

Comment: How do I do that?. I tried to do `(define-key flyspell-mode-map (kbd "<f12>") 'flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word)`. But then my `f` key stopped working. As in the letter `f` of the keyboard. :)

Comment: @minibuffer I intentionally wrote *customize*. If you use the customization interface the input `<f12>` works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not a fan of _customize_ except to change colors on faces etc.  The reason is after a while I might forget I made this change and not know what I did. When I have a piece of code on my init file it is more _tangible_ for me.

Comment: You don't have to use the Customize interface to change the aforementioned variable.